# Azure link VNET to Private DNS with Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli, vnet, azure-private-dns

I'm working on an Azure CLI script to automate the creation of a vnet in our cloud infrastructure. One of the parts in this script is linking a VNET to a Azure Private DNS. This should be easy, but apperently the difficulty is the fact that the VNET and the Private DNS are in a different resourcegroup.

This is my script;

```
   az network private-dns link vnet create --name MyLink \
     --registration-enabled true \
     --resource-group my-vnet-resourcegroup\
     --subscription 'My Subscription' \
     --tags Domain=MyDomain \
     --virtual-network my-own-vnet \
     --zone-name myzone.nu
```

Now when exuting i'm getting the following error;

***Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'myzone.nu' not found.***

So I updated the script to look at the resourcegroup for the private DNS;

```
   az network private-dns link vnet create --name MyLink \
     --registration-enabled true \
     --resource-group my-privatedns-resourcegroup \
     --subscription 'My Subscription' \
     --tags Domain=MyDomain \
     --virtual-network my-own-vnet \
     --zone-name myzone.nu
```

This gives me the following error;

***Deployment failed. Correlation ID: (SomeGuid). Virtual network resource not found for '/subscriptions//resourceGroups/my-privatedns-resourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/my-own-vnet'***

I'm quite stuck at the moment on how to fix this. Anybody else ran into this before? I'm open to suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass virtual network Id to the private DNS link vNet creation if the Virtual network is in another resource group which differs from your DNS zone resource group.

```
VnetID=$(az network vnet show -g vnet-rg -n my-vnet --query 'id' -o tsv)
az network private-dns link vnet create -n mylink -e true -g dns-rg -z myzone.nu -v $VnetID
```

[image]

or, you could use [Azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-getstarted-powershell#create-a-private-dns-zone).

```
$vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -name my-own-vnet -ResourceGroupName my-vnet-resourcegroup

New-AzPrivateDnsVirtualNetworkLink -ZoneName private.contoso.com `
  -ResourceGroupName MyAzureResourceGroup -Name "mylink" `
  -VirtualNetworkId $vnet.id -EnableRegistration
```

Comment: superb, this was the way to go. Thank you very much!